# Google Maps - Access object returned by getbounds

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a simple Google Maps implementation with an editable circle, the 'bounds' object that it creates looks like this...

[image]

I am trying to convert these values to an array so I can save them to a database.  First I want to try and understand what each value represents.

`Googles Docs` say that getbounds returns a rectangle so I am confused.  Anybody have any relevant docs they can point me at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds) object.

It has getNorthEast and getSouthWest methods to get the two corners (and can be used to create a google.maps.Rectangle)

Comment: So a circle is essentially just a rectangle as far as bounds are concerned?

Comment: More square than rectangular, but yes, a bounds is always rectangular.